# Требуется ли обособление?

Tags: пунктуация

Подойдите к банку, забрать деньги. Почему?

Comment: неа, запятая лишнее

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **подойдите к банку забрать деньги.**

При глаголах движения и положения может находиться инфинитив в роли **обстоятельства цели:** поехали встречать, приехал погостить, присел отдохнуть.

**В устной речи** здесь возможна пауза, тогда инфинитив приобретает значение **уточнения.**

Также это предложение можно рассматривать как СПП **с пропущенным союзом**: Подойдите к банку, (чтобы) забрать деньги.